# How can I populate image value from ConfigMap in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I want to write docker image name in kubernetes config and then use it in in my deployment file instead of directly hardcoding it.
So instead of:

**`image: "nginx:latest`"**

I want to do following:

```
image:
 valueFrom:
  configMapKeyRef:
   name: docker-config
   key: docker-image
```

How can it be done or any other alternatives?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to **update** the **value** of image key you can use following **data-driven commands** by using **set** verb for example

```
  # Set a deployment's nginx container image to 'nginx:1.9.1', and its busybox container image to 'busybox'.
  kubectl set image deployment/nginx busybox=busybox nginx=nginx:1.9.1

  # Update all deployments' and rc's nginx container's image to 'nginx:1.9.1'
  kubectl set image deployments,rc nginx=nginx:1.9.1 --all

  # Update image of all containers of daemonset abc to 'nginx:1.9.1'
  kubectl set image daemonset abc *=nginx:1.9.1

  # Print result (in yaml format) of updating nginx container image from local file, without hitting the server
  kubectl set image -f path/to/file.yaml nginx=nginx:1.9.1 --local -o yaml
```

you can get more detail by using

```
kubectl set image --help
```

here are more example for [updating-resources](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#updating-resources)

Answer (score 4):

it is not a correct approach to update image value from configmap. There could be other ways as well. One way i can think of achieving is with the below command

```
cat some-depl.yaml | run 'sed' command to update image value | kubectl apply -f -
```

Comment: thanks for answer, i am now using jinja2 to generate this.

Comment: good to know. jinja2 is also one of the way to update run time values over template

Comment: @MayankSenani can you update this question with your answer ?

Answer (score 3):

There's only a limited set of things you can do with ConfigMap values: you can mount them as files into pods, or you can use them to set environment variables, but that's it.

It's common to use a higher-level tool that can apply templating to your Kubernetes configuration for this task (and in particular specifying the image's tag is extremely routine).  I'm most familiar with [Helm](https://helm.sh/) but there are a variety of other tools.

In Helm you would have to create a [chart](https://docs.helm.sh/developing_charts/).  This has a couple of parts, but it lets you specify a default set of values in a `values.yaml` file:

```
tag: 1.9.1
```

Then it uses the Go `"text/template"` language to generate Kubernetes YAML files, as in a `templates/nginx-deployment.yaml` file:

```
image: nginx:{{ .Values.tag }}
```

When you want to actually go install it, you can provide alternate values that will get filled into the templates

```
helm install . --set tag=1.15.8
```

Comment: helm is much more than just templating, so i decided to use jinja2 for this.